# Terraform Build timed-out in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, build, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create topic , BQ subscription and schema with the the help of terraform but the build is getting timed-out after 20min .

```
  resource "google_pubsub_schema" "job_schema" {
  name = "HISTORY_TEMP"
  type = "AVRO"
  definition = file("./hist.json")
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "bq_topic" {
  name = "cdw-cf-bq-temp"
  
  schema_settings {
    schema   = "projects/project_id/schemas/HIST_TEMP"
    encoding = "JSON"
    }
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "bq_subscription" {
  name  = "cdw-cf-bq-temp-subs"
  topic = "cdw-cf-bq-temp"
  
bigquery_config {
        table               = "project:dataset_id.table"
        use_topic_schema    = true
        write_metadata      = false
        drop_unknown_fields = false 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please [increase the Terraform logging verbosity](https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging) to help with troubleshooting by exporting the variable `TF_LOG=TRACE` for more debugging information?

Comment: thanks @JakeNelson, I have enabled trace and error it shows as :                                                                                                                                                  Info
2022-10-18 09:46:47.979 AEDTStep #3 - "apply": "error": {
Info
2022-10-18 09:46:47.979 AEDTStep #3 - "apply": "code": 500,
Info
2022-10-18 09:46:47.979 AEDTStep #3 - "apply": "message": "A service error has occurred. Please retry your request. If the error persists, please report it. [code=e8c0]" google_pubsub_topic.bq_topic: Still creating...

Comment: Hi @Mudgal, Can you check whether the Pub/Sub API is enabled in your project?

Comment: thanks all, its working fine , there were some permissions issue as BQ subscription requires special permission .

Comment: Hi @Mudgal, If your issue is resolved, can you provide the resolution steps as the answer?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT please see below  for permissions required for BQ subscription :                                    service-***@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com      -- Role -> BigQuery Data Editor                                           ,BigQuery Metadata Viewer,Cloud Pub/Sub Service Agent

Answer (score 0):

Three different resources help you manage your IAM policy for BigQuery dataset. Each of these resources serves a different use case:

- `google_bigquery_dataset_iam_policy:` Authoritative. Sets the IAM policy for the dataset and replaces any existing policy already attached.
- `google_bigquery_dataset_iam_binding:` Authoritative for a given role. Updates the IAM policy to grant a role to a list of members. Other roles within the IAM policy for the dataset are preserved.
- `google_bigquery_dataset_iam_member:` Non-authoritative. Updates the IAM policy to grant a role to a new member. Other members for the role for the dataset are preserved.

For more information, you can refer to this [document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_dataset_iam).

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.